# Deserialising JSON Data

Tags: jquery, json

I've an example string being return through a post call to an ASP handler.

```
alert("Data: " + data);
```

Is working and alerting the string.

```
[{"Item1":"stringone","Item2":"stringtwo"}]
```

I cant seem to be able to access the data in Item1 and Item2 so I can enter it into a textbox?

```
$('#txtFOA').val(data[0]);
$('#txtAddress').val(data[2]);
```

Comment: If you do a `console.log(data)`, does it show as a string or as an object?

Comment: This shows data as a string

Comment: Assuming `data` is a string: `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: @Adam92, If the data is shown as a string, you will need to explicity cast it to a JSON object by using `JSON.parse(data)` or `$.parseJSON(data)` first

Comment: This is now giving me "     [object Object]    "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first parse that string to JSON like this:

```
var jsonified = JSON.parse(data);
```

then you can access its elements like this:

```
jsonified[0].Item1
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('#txtFOA').val(data[0].Item1);
$('#txtAddress').val(data[2].Item2);
```

Answer (score 0):

data[0] returns the entire object

```
{
  "Item1": "stringone",
  "Item2": "stringtwo"
}
```

If you want to enter "stringone" in textbox, use something like this

```
data[0].Item1
or 
data[0]["Item1"]
```

Also you can't access data[2] in this case, since you have only one element in your result array.

```
$('#txtFOA').val(data[0].Item1);
$('#txtAddress').val(data[0].Item2);

or 

$('#txtFOA').val(data[0]["Item1"]);
$('#txtAddress').val(data[0]["Item2"]);
```